# How to create docker image in Spring Boot project

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, docker

I have tried using  spotify/docker-maven-plugin without any success .

Below is part of my pom.xml file

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
  <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${dockerfile-maven-version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>build</goal>
        <goal>push</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <repository>myrepo/maven-docker-spotify</repository>
    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
    <buildArgs>
      <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</JAR_FILE>
    </buildArgs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you please state your problem with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [spotify/docker-maven-plugin](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin) you are using is currently inactive. It's recommended using [spotify/dockerfile-maven-plugin](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven) instead.

So change the plugin section of your pom.xml file to resemble below

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
  <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${dockerfile-maven-version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>build</goal>
        <goal>push</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <repository>spotify/foobar</repository>
    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
    <buildArgs>
      <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
    </buildArgs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note: You can also try using [JIB](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin) maven plugin that doesnt require you to have docker installed and works with minimal configuration. With JIB, Running below command in is enough to do the jo

```
mvn compile com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:0.9.2:dockerBuild
```

Comment: That work for me. I will look at the jib maven plugin